# How to tell if my browsers are infected by ADROZEK?

Tags: virus, browser-extensions

MS has exposed ADROZEK:
https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-exposes-adrozek-malware-that-hijacks-chrome-edge-and-firefox/

I would like to know if the browsers (Chrome, blue ff) of my Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS are infected.
After a few searches, nothing came up.
Perhaps it's still too soon?

PD: I wasn't allowed to add the "adrozek" tag

Comment: *"I would like to know if the browsers (Chrome, blue ff) of my Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS are infected."* - do they show any symptoms associated with the malware?

Comment: Hi @Steffen Ullrich I can't tell, that;s why I'd like to check.   
I think that the behavior is not evident, in order to being able to control the infected PCs for long time.  
Actually, my question, to myself, is "do I have the malware without noticing it?".  
Usually I don;t care because there are not many threats for Linux, but in this case, the target are the browsers.  
MS says that ADROZEK comes with those downloaded installers offered in the web for lile downloads, security scans or the like, which I avoid carefully.

Comment: The article you link to  lists the symptoms of the infection. If the symptoms are not there you are likely not infected.

Comment: Yes, it enumerates the modifications introduced by ADROSEK.  
I expected to find an utility capable of checking them all quickly, instead of having to go thru an extensive manual checks procedure (made up of steps I'm not sure I could perform in a finite time, given my "Ubuntu consumer" profile - more than expert).|
As the article say it's being a bi thing, I imagined that such a tool might already be available.

Comment: It not only says what was changed on the browser what are the visible effects - notably more ads. If you don't see the effects you are likely not infected.